# How to do something within each group and col in groups with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df such as:

```
    cluster_name    qseqid  sseqid  pident  length  qstart  qend
cluster_000001      seq1    YP_009416.1 57.4    61  0   182
cluster_000001      seq2    NP_592.1    24.1    349 68  1081
cluster_000002      seq4    YP_009695.1 25.7    249 0   725
cluster_000002      seq3    YP_009695.1 25.8    291 0   818
cluster_000003      seq8    YP_002675.1 25.8    291 0   818
```

and within each cluster I would like to do something with each values of sseqid, in other word I should be something like:

```
for cluster in blast.groupby('cluster_name'): 
    for row in blast['sseqid']:
        print(row)
        print("ok")
```

and then the result should be:

```
YP_009416.1
NP_592.1
ok
YP_009695.1
YP_009695.1
ok 
YP_002675.1
```

But it does not work.

Comment: What does mean "does not work"? Do you get some error, unexpected output or nothing happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for _, cluster in blast.groupby('cluster_name'): 
    for row in cluster['sseqid']:
        print(row)
    print("ok")
```